# Filename ascending every upload

Tags: php, numbers, concatenation

I have this code to generate a random name for every uploaded image on my web:

```
$str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"; 
$cad = ""; 
    for($i=0;$i<12;$i++) { 
        $cad .= substr($str,rand(0,62),1); 
    }
```

The problem is when I want to show ascending images but the name is random, so, it doesn't have any order. I can have an image named "sAbaw712.png" but if I have another named "aAd217812.png", the second one will be displayed first than the first one.

How can I create a code who create a String ascending like:

1.png, 2.png, 3.png

Thanks

Comment: Uh, append a number to your random string?

Comment: No, I don't wanna my random string. I wanna a "for" who can make a string like: 1.png, 2.png, 3.png.. @JayBlanchard

Comment: You read all of the files from your image directory and find the one with the highest number. Add 1 to that and save your latest upload with the new name.

Comment: Just stating the obvious here: If you do this, the resulting filenames will not be random anymore, e.g. users might be able to guess filenames.

Comment: Instead, you could use a known prefix (like the number) and append a random suffix to it. Then you could use some kind of matching on your existing files to obtain the highest index and increase that + append a new random string. So: 0001_asdn.png, 0002_2rh8.png, ...